# I cannot open ANACONDA Navigator

Tags: python, xml, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, xml-parsing

I completed all the steps described in the Anaconda troubleshot documantation but I could not accomplish to initialise it. Here is the anaconda prompt traceback code:

```
(base) C:\Users\DELL>anaconda navigator

Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    
from binstar_client.scripts.cli import main
  
File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    
from .errors import *
  
File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\binstar_client\errors.py", line 1, in 

<module>
    
from clyent.errors import ClyentError
  
File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\clyent\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    
from pkg_resources import iter_entry_points
  
File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    
import plistlib
  
File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\plistlib.py", line 61, in <module>
    
from xml.parsers.expat import ParserCreate

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xml.parsers'
```

I think ı should import the module called xml.parsers however ı could not find out how to do it. I need someone to help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lite, cmd version using `conda` commands, it is the preferred option to activate environment and install packages.

Reference: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands.html